# TextFormField not resetting its Initial Value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, textfield

I'm somewhat new to `Flutter` so I don't know if this is the "correct" way of updating data collected from a server. In my case, what I'm doing is (my app code is quite long, I think the description below will suffice):

1. Let the user create a custom form for a given date.
2. Have him upload the data to a server (more specifically, `Firebase`).
3. If he clicks on a date, the form should be updated to the most recent one saved on `Firebase`.

   - To do this, I'm deleting all of the `TextFormField` widgets (they are held in a `Map` which I reset with `widgetsMap = {}`, which is also what I do for the form data itself) and rebuilding them with the data retrieved from `Firebase`.
   - The `TextFormField` should have an initial value based on what was retrieved from `Firebase`. To achieve this, I've tried to use a `controller` and an `initialValue`, but neither have worked.

     - The **problem** is that, if I want to update the initial value of a field a second time, the previous one will remain. For example, if `date 1` has an initial value of `Hello` and `date 2` has an initial value of `World`; when I click on `date 2` coming from `date 1`, although the `TextFormField` widgets (there might even be a different number of them) will be built correctly, the initial value shown will still be `Hello`.

So what is happening? Shouldn't the `initialValue` of a widget be wiped out once the widget and the data have been reset? Do those objects still exist in the background somewhere even after I have reset them with `= {}` (I thought that, since `dart` is a garbage-collected language, these objects would be deleted once the references to them disappear...)?

Comment: Could you paste some code?

Comment: @FilipP. , why did you delete your previous answer? I've just tested it and it does seem to be working. I'm using both a `key` and an `initialValue` now. So it would be something like: `TextFormField(key: Key(widget.initialValue), initialValue: widget.initialValue, ...)`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add `Key` to `TextFormField`. You can use `Key(initialValue)`. For example:

```dart
TextFormField(
  key: Key(widget.initialValue),
  initialValue: widget.initialValue),
  ...
)
```

Although you reset your own map of `TextFormField`s, if you put new `TextFormField`s in same position in the widget tree, the `Flutter` framework will reuse the previous state. Setting the `Key` will tell `Flutter` that this is a different widget.

Comment: Do you mean something like `final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>()`? I've tried to wrap all the `TextFormField`s in a `Form` and then call `_formKey.currentState.reset()` in the `initState` but it didn't seem to work. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Shouldn't this be somewhat of a bug of the `TextFormField`? I thought `Flutter` widgets were supposed to be *completely* rebuilt in the `build` method, and *not* have any references to previous widgets.

Comment: Stateless widgets are rebuild every time. StatefulWidget's state is not. It's persisted to obviously keep the state and TextFormField is StatefulWidget. If you put the same type on StatefulWidget in the same location in the widget tree state will be reused. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html

Comment: Yes, *but* I expected that behavior only if I had not deleted the `StatefulWidget`. In my case, I delete the `StatefulWidget` (`widgetsMap = {}`) every time I have to do an update through `Firebase`. If they supposedly don't exist anymore, where is the previous state being tracked? Should it really be tracked if I deliberately deleted it?

Comment: It's difficult for me to tell you more without seeing the code and what exactly you do.

Comment: I understand your point of view, but it's kind of difficult for me to share it because it's corporate code at this point and not very short either. In sum, I retrieve the form data from `Firebase`, and use a `Map` to store the widgets I build based on that same data, always deleting the previous widgets (`= {}`). Once that's done, after a `notifyListeners()` the new widgets are rendered on the screen via a `ListView.builder` (maybe that's where we would find remnants of the previous widget objects?).

Comment: ok Ive tried this method but the keyboard keeps dissapearing when editing the field